# Accessing a Global Variable in an External Class

Tags: python, global-variables, scope, python-2.6

I've been learning Python for about a week or so and after my code getting quite large and a bit messy I decided to break it out into separate class files etc. etc. but I've come across a bit of a problem.

I've tried Googling and searching here on SO but I couldn't find my specific problem so forgive me if it has been asked before.

Consider 2 files.  test.py and testClass.py  I have a global variable in test.py which will also be SET in test.py but I want to access that variable in a function in testClass.py.  Here's some code to help explain.

test.py would look like this:

```
import testClass

dict = {}
z = 5

dict['test'] = testClass.testClass(1, 3)

print dict['test'].sum()
```

testClass.py would look like this:

```
class testClass:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.foo = x
        self.bar = y

    def sum(self):
        global z
        return self.foo + self.bar + z
```

Currently the interpreter is spitting out:

```
NameError: global name 'z' is not defined
```

After re-reading the Python references for classes and variable scope I thought I had it nailed but obviously not.

The outcome of this all is simply to be able to iter through a dictionary of object instances and run a sequence of various check functions etc contained within the external class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Global is global to the file (module) so you might want to include it in a class.

Comment: I was thinking I might simply have to pass it to the instance but was more curious to know if it was possible the way I was originally thinking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if global would work if you declare it inside a method since that is technically a local namespace. Try putting it outside of the main and sum.

Comment: This is a bit incomplete for a full answer, please provide some code or docs to what you're suggesting! :)

Answer (score 0):

Globals need to be defined in any function that would otherwise alter them.

I think you need to define 'z' as a global in test.py as well:

```
import testClass

dict = {}
global z = 5

dict['test'] = testClass.testClass(1, 3)

print dict['test'].sum()
```

Comment: False answer, globals don't work that way, they are accessible by variable name in a module-level only.